# Find if there is a repeated value of a field in result set

Tags: mysql, oracle, sql-server-2008

I have result set like this :

```
A    B
-------
1    10
2    10
2    10 
3    10
4    10
5    10
```

I am selecting the values of A corresponding to value of B e.g corresponding to 10 as value of B There are different values of A such as 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5.

I want to know that is there a repeated value in A for any value of B. As in this case 2 is repeated so answer in this case is YES.

Comment: Out of curiosity am asking, What is the purpose of this? Just to find duplicates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In standard ANSI SQL you could simply use GROUP BY:

```
select a, b
  from my_table
 group by a, b
having count(*) > 1
```

This will return every combination of `a` and `b` for which there is more then one row and it will work on every RDBMS specified.

Answer (score 0):

use a group by

```
SQL>   with data as (select rownum A ,   10 B from dual connect by level <= 5
  2                union all
  3                select 2 A ,   10 B from dual)
  4  select b, case when count(*) - count(distinct a) > 0 then 'YES' else 'NO' end has_dups
  5    from data
  6   group by b;

         B HAS
---------- ---
        10 YES

SQL>
SQL> with data as (select rownum A ,   10 B from dual connect by level <= 5
  2                union all
  3                select 2 A ,   10 B from dual)
  4  select b, a dup_val, count(*) number_of_dups
  5    from data
  6   group by b, a
  7   having count(*) > 1;

         B    DUP_VAL NUMBER_OF_DUPS
---------- ---------- --------------
        10          2              2
```